# Реализация dependecyproperty в рамка паттерна MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependencyproperty

Всем добрый день, у меня вопрос как реализовывать dependecyproperty в usercontrol, сохраняя целостность паттерна MVVM в WPF? В существующих темах по этому вопросу, были предложены решения с реализацией dependecyproperty в code-behind usercontrol'а, разве это не нарушение паттерна? Как в таком случае красиво передать значения в viewmodel userconrol'a?
Ответом на данный вопрос может быть рабочая реализация dependecyproperty в viewmodel, а не в code-behind или аргументированный вывод о том, что этого сделать нельзя.
Хороший пример есть тут: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247633/binding-usercontrol-dependency-property-and-mvvm)

Comment: DependencyProperty являются частью уровня представления (View), нет никаких проблем в реализации их в code behind. Петтерн MVVM не требует, чтобы весь код представления был в XAML, он лишь требует, чтобы код, не относящийся к представлению, был вынесен из представления (как из XAML, так и из code behind) в VM или даже в M.

Comment: .xaml.cs ни в коей мере не является VM, это тоже часть V.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, получается, что использование DP не предполагает обработку этих данных, тк V не занимается обработкой. То есть нельзя просто передать данные в UserControl через DP и провести какое либо действие с ними, тк VM про DP ничего не знает

Comment: Обработкой данных занимается VM (или делегирует это модели). Свойства VM получают значения из V через Binding DP к свойствам VM. Обработка запускается либо по команде (ICommand в VM, привязанная к чему-то в V), либо по изменению данных в VM. Либо ещё как-то.

Comment: Но кроме обработки данных может быть ещё преопразование данных для нужд V (например, значение от 0 до 100 можно преобразовать в угол от 0 до 180). Это обычно чистая логика UI, и её место снова-таки в V.

Comment: Смысл паттерна MVVM во многом состоит в том, чтобы отделить логику отображения от бизнес-логики и логики модели, и чтобы логика представления находилась в V, а остальное в VM и М.